# Is it possible to apply and/or condition in angular js directives?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have one checkbox.If it is checked then i want to show includeMergedInsureds and includeExpiredInsured I was trying to use AND between two but its not working any suggestions will be appreciated.

```
       data-ng-model='vm.searchCriteria.includeMergedInsureds and vm.searchCriteria.includeExpiredInsureds'
```

Comment: you can watch the values of vm.searchCriteria.includeMergedInsureds and vm.searchCriteria.includeExpiredInsureds and update a third value with their result, and then bind the check box to that third value

Answer (score 1):

if you want the checkbox to toggle multiple things add a method to your controller thats what the controller is for

```
$scope.setItemProps = function(val) { $scope.item1 = val; scope.item2 = val;}
```

and then on your checkbox

```
<checkbox ng-click="setItemProps(true)" >
```

you can use && and || there and groupings so you could do things like this

```
<element ng-show="(item1 && item2) || item3">
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that includeMergedInsureds and includeExpiredInsured are other checkboxes, you probably want to have an ng-show on those other checkboxes.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.searchCriteria.includeInsureds">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.searchCriteria.includeMergedInsureds" ng-show="vm.searchCriteria.includeInsureds">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.searchCriteria.includeExpiredInsureds" ng-show="vm.searchCriteria.includeInsureds">
```